# Dynamically adding pages in cognos reports

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-8, cognos-bi

I have a requirement to fulfill where i have to fetch data from the data source.. In that the number of pages in a report might vary due to the number of times the customer has purchased. Basically Customer Number is the primary Key and based on the Customer Number the report will run and each invoice will be in a different page. The template of invoice will be same except for few values. It is in pdf format.. 
My question is how can i create a report in such a way it takes the default template and creates many invoices based on the number of invoices present .....

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to Page Explorer and add a Page Set.
2. Set Query property for your page set
3. Put your page inside set
4. Set proper Grouping and Sorting property for your page set.

Comment: can u explain how to use grouping and sorting in page set?

Comment: I gave more details. I think this correction will make process clear.